# Grouped Table View - Realizing which cell was selected

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsarray

I am making a grouped a table view with multiple sections (using NSArrays). Anyway, normally, if I have a regular table view with NO sections I am able to use the following code to realize which cell the user tapped. This no longer works since I use NSArrays to split up the table and don't place the cell names directly into the table view code (`[tblSimpleTable addObject:@"cell 1"];`  <-- I don't do that). What new code should I use?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if ([[tblSimpleTable objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] isEqual:@"iPhone"]) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the Row number and the section number

Try something like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section==yoursection)
    {
    if(indexPath.row==yourRow)
    {
       //do something
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was playing around with it while waiting for an answer and used a switch statement, but that's the same exact thing. Thanks for your help.